# UITableView with two custom cells not appearing properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a grouped tableview that consists of two rows and each row has a custom tableview cell.  I have the custom tableview classes and cell identifiers all established and associated with the tableview rows in interface builder.  My first tableview cell appears fine, but the second one seems to have the same properties as the first cell.  However, once I tap the second cell then tap the first cell, the second cell switches to the correct cell design.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EditCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EditCell
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        //Do some stuff
        return cell
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DeleteCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DeleteCell
        //Do some stuff
        return cell
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EditCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EditCell
        // Now you can access the subclass attributes by doing : (cell as! EditCell).theAttribute
    } else {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DeleteCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DeleteCell
    }

    return cell
}
```

Create only one cell object in scope and, depending on the row, initialize the object as an instance of one your specific UITableViewCell subclasses.

UPDATE: Added a comment on how to access the UITableViewCell subclass attributes.

Comment: Makes sense, but I'm getting an error when I try to set the cell properties in the first if statement.  For instance, EditCell has a `UITextField IBOutlet`, but when I set it, I get an error saying `Value of type UITableViewCell has no member titleField`.    For some reason the cell is staying as type `UITableViewCell` rather than changing to `EditCell`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add this tidbit to my answer. Just do this: `(cell as! EditCell).titleField`

Comment: Wow!  that worked perfectly, but why is `(cell as! EditCell).titleField` necessary?  Didn't we cast the cell as EditCell in this line `cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EditCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EditCell`?

Comment: @Brosef The `(cell as! EditCell)` is necessary because the cell object was initially typed as a UITableViewCell. See the second line of my code: `let cell: UITableViewCell!`. The cell object is expecting an instance of UITableViewCell, your EditCell class is a subclass of UITableViewCell, so it won't complain. Although, to access the subclass methods, you'll need to do use the pesky `as!`.

Comment: Yes cell was initially typed as UITableViewCell, but doesn't `cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EditCellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EditCell` change cell to EditCell?  It seems redundant to do both.

Comment: @Brosef This is actually [a forced conversion](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23). Cell is expecting a UITableViewCell instance. There is no guarantee that the conversion will be successful. Although, since we're converting to a subclass, it will work. The downfall is having to use `as!` all the time. The benefit is that `cell` can now be replaced with any subclass of UITableViewCell.